# Get value of attribute added to the dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, attributes

```
<option visible="False" value="5"></option>
```

This is a ASP.NET dropdownlist

I have added an extra attribute visible in code behind. Now I want to get the value of visible attribute with jQuery.

Say the name of the dropdownlist is `VehiclesList`

I have tried:

```
var value = $('#ctl00_MainContent_dropdownlist option:selected').attr('Visible')
```

but the value is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please show how the HTML will look *with* the additional attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$isVisible = $('select option:selected').attr('visible');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GTPaK/

Comment: what am I doing wrong in var value = $('#ctl00_MainContent_dropdownlist option:selected').attr('Visible')

Comment: "ctl00_MainContent_dropdownlist" this should be the id of select tag check your html or show me ..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have id in select

```
$('#test option:selected').attr('title');
```

that you way you can grab that value.